# ¿Cómo puedo traer estos datos a google spreadheet?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas

Necesito llevarme el valor recalculado del IPC desde [acá](http://encina.ine.cl/CALCULADORA/reportes/xmlVariacion.asp?a1=2017&a2=2017&m1=2&m2=3&valor=390000) con una fórmula. Estaba viendo que `importXML` puede ser una alternativa, pero como es un árbol de la estructura XML la hoja de cálculo de google no me trae la información.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cuál fue el xPath con el que intentaste obtener los datos? ¿Cuál fue el resultado mostrado? Sería conveniente que siguieras el [tour] y leyeras [ask] para entender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sí, voy a ser más cuidadoso. En todo caso ya lo resolví. Tal como me indicaste, fue necesario seguir el xPath de la estructura del xml. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Al final ocupé una fórmula que me permitió conseguir lo que necesitaba.
Conste que la celda Y11 es la fecha inicial, mientras que la T11 corresponde al valor que quise calcular la variabilidad del IPC.

El resultado de la fórmula me arroja el monto reconvertido al día de hoy, menos 2 meses (por eso "MES(HOY())-2"), dado que en la calculadora del INE no se presenta la variación ni del presente mes ni de la del mes inmediatamente anterior.

Para INE, a1 es el año inicial, a2 es el año actual, m1 es el mes inicial y m2 es el mes actual.

"Datos" es la etiqueta que de acuerdo a la estructura .xml, posee mayor jerarquía; "Datas" es aquella que le sigue, y como en este caso es el único dato mayor a 1, filtré la etiqueta que tuviese un valor superior a 1.

> `=importxml("http://encina.ine.cl/CALCULADORA/reportes/xmlVariacion.asp?a1="&AÑO(Y11)&"&a2="&AÑO(HOY())&"&m1="&MES(Y11)&"&m2="&MES(HOY())-2&"&valor="&T11&"";"Datos/Datas[Vari>1.00]"))`